# Computing the limit of this sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I recently found a problem in a calculus book which asked to prove the convergence of the sequence $$ a_n=\prod_{k=2}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{k^2} \right) $$ for $n\geq 2$.

Establishing the convergence is just an application of the monotonic sequence theorem, but I can't see what the limit of the sequence is. My first guess would have been zero, but a search on google told me that the limit of this sequence should be $\frac1{\zeta(2)}$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. In particular, it's not zero. Is there a more elementary way of computing this limit?

Comment: The limit seems to be a tad simpler, namely $1/2$.

Comment: Right, the zeta function shows up only when I take the product above over prime numbers, not over all integers from 1 to $n$.

Comment: That makes sense. A prime example of the importance of summation indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite $a_n$ as
$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \prod_{k=2}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)
= \prod_{k=2}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right) \\
&= \prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k+1}{k} \prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k}
= \frac{n+1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n} \tag{Cancellations}
\\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$$
*(so, in particular, it is not $\zeta(2)^{-1}$).*